# Cannot get the tables from website using pandas and selenium

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, selenium

Trying the following code to get all information like price, location, area, etc. of the listed real estate. I have the following code which is returning `No tables found`:

```
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get("https://uybor.uz/en/prodazha-kvartir/kvartiry-v-tashkente?page=2")

html = driver.page_source

tables = pd.read_html(html)
data = tables[1]

driver.close()
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

There is no table present on the web page.However you can use `BeautifulSoup` to fetch `location`,`area` and `price` and load into `Pandas` `Dataframe`.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://uybor.uz/en/prodazha-kvartir/kvartiry-v-tashkente?page=2")
time.sleep(5)
html = driver.page_source
driver.close()
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')

location=[]
loc_area=[]
price=[]
for loc in soup.find_all('span',class_='listing__subtitle')[:-2]:
    location.append(loc.text)

for loc_a in soup.find_all('span',class_='listing__param-text',text=re.compile('Floor space:'))[:-1]:
    loc_area.append(loc_a.next_element.next_element.strip())

for p in soup.find_all('div',class_='listing__price')[:-1]:
    price.append(p.text)

df = pd.DataFrame({"Location":location,"Area":loc_area,"Price":price})
print(df)
```

### Output printed on console.

```
        Area                                           Location        Price
0       47 м²       Tashkent city, district Sirgali, Kuruvchilar   22 372 usd
1       62 м²     Tashkent city, district Yakkasaray, Bobur bogi   45 000 usd
2       40 м²        Tashkent city, district Chilanzar, Чиланзар   25 500 usd
3       70 м²   Tashkent city, district Mirza Ulugbek, Измайлова   73 000 usd
4      120 м²  Tashkent city, district Mirza Ulugbek, Муртазаева   95 000 usd
5       76 м²      Tashkent city, district Shaykhantahur, Chorsu   29 999 usd
6       70 м²  Tashkent city, district Mirza Ulugbek, Tamary ...   34 999 usd
7       63 м²  Tashkent city, district Shaykhantahur, Хадра,Ц...   41 000 usd
8       50 м²  Tashkent city, district Mirabad, Массив Панельный   18 999 usd
9      108 м²       Tashkent city, district Sirgali, Kuruvchilar   51 409 usd
10     111 м²     Tashkent city, district Shaykhantahur, Jangokh   88 000 usd
11      60 м²  Tashkent city, district Mirza Ulugbek, Аккурга...   45 000 usd
12      50 м²  Tashkent city, district Shaykhantahur, Kichik ...   29 797 usd
13      52 м²      Tashkent city, district Yashnabad, Aviasozlar   25 500 usd
14      40 м²  Tashkent city, district Mirabad, Транспортный ...   22 000 usd
15      63 м²  Tashkent city, district Shaykhantahur, Халклар...   45 000 usd
16      57 м²       Tashkent city, district Shaykhantahur, Ganga   45 000 usd
17      78 м²             Tashkent city, district Mirabad, Nukus   58 000 usd
18     100 м²  Tashkent city, district Yunusabad, Kashgar (Ц-4)    78 000 usd
19      70 м²    Tashkent city, district Almazar, Karakamysh-2/4   39 984 usd
20     105 м²           Tashkent city, district Almazar, Olimpia   67 321 usd
21      33 м²      Tashkent city, district Uchtepa, Chilanzar-12   22 500 usd
22      82 м²       Tashkent city, district Yakkasaray, Kushbegi   62 000 usd
23      38 м²        Tashkent city, district Yakkasaray, Bashlyk   22 800 usd
24      45 м²  Tashkent city, district Shaykhantahur, Labzak ...   44 000 usd
25      60 м²  Tashkent city, district Shaykhantahur, Тинчлик...   28 200 usd
26     132 м²     Tashkent city, district Chilanzar, Chilanzar-2  115 000 usd
27      48 м²   Tashkent city, district Mirza Ulugbek, Yalangach   26 500 usd
28      75 м²  Tashkent city, district Mirza Ulugbek, Новомос...   54 000 usd
29      70 м²     Tashkent city, district Chilanzar, Chilanzar-C   49 000 usd
30     128 м²  Tashkent city, district Yakkasaray, Ул. Кунаев...  190 000 usd
31      59 м²  Tashkent city, district Shaykhantahur, Шайхант...   42 000 usd
32      78 м²  Tashkent city, district Almazar, Северный Алма...   33 500 usd
33      85 м²  Tashkent city, district Mirabad, метро Ташкент...   73 000 usd
34      95 м²    Tashkent city, district Almazar, Karakamysh-2/4   58 694 usd
35      73 м²          Tashkent city, district Chilanzar, Mukimi   56 000 usd
36  108.90 м²  Tashkent city, district Yakkasaray, Kichik Bes...   Negotiable
37      74 м²     Tashkent city, district Yunusabad, Yunusabad-4   Negotiable
38      79 м²  Tashkent city, district Shaykhantahur, Labzak ...   45 700 usd
39      53 м²  Tashkent city, district Mirabad, Нукусская, ор...   38 000 usd
40      62 м²  Tashkent city, district Mirza Ulugbek, Oltinte...   Negotiable
41     119 м²  Tashkent city, district Yakkasaray, ул. Баходи...   Negotiable
42   99.70 м²     Tashkent city, district Chilanzar, Chilanzar-C   86 005 usd
43      85 м²      Tashkent city, district Uchtepa, Chilanzar-25   47 800 usd
44     110 м²  Tashkent city, district Yunusabad, Abdully Kadyri  155 000 usd
45      80 м²    Tashkent city, district Yunusabad, Yunusabad-15   55 000 usd
46      55 м²       Tashkent city, district Sirgali, Kuruvchilar   26 181 usd
47  130.94 м²  Tashkent city, district Yakkasaray, ул. Кичик ...   92 582 usd
48     135 м²  Tashkent city, district Shaykhantahur, Kichik ...   80 453 usd
49     105 м²       Tashkent city, district Mirabad, Yakkachinor   77 990 usd
```